# Typescript how to define object in which key's value depends on another key

Tags: json, typescript, interface

I am new to typescript and stuck in defining type of JSON object. In the following examples I want to define the type for `myJSONObject`. The required types which I defined are `JSONType_1` and `JSONType_2`.

```
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>
    & {
      [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>
    }[Keys];

interface NetworkIdOptions {
  group?: string;
  individual?: string;
}

type NetworkId = RequireOnlyOne<NetworkIdOptions, 'group' | 'individual'>;

export interface JSONType_1 {
  networkId: NetworkId;
  tasks: Array<
  | taskInterface_1
  | taskInterface_2
  | taskInterface_3
  >;
}
export interface JSONType_2 {
  networkId: {
    group: 'myFavGroup';
  };
  tasks: Array<
  | taskInterface_4
  | taskInterface_5
  >;
}
```

As per this `networkId` can either have `group` key or `individual` key.
When `networkId` has `group` key and who's value is = `myFavGroup`, then I want this object to be type of `JSONType_2`.
Notice the `tasks` changes when group name is `myFavGroup`.
Use case for above defined `JSONType_1` & `JSONType_2`:

```
myFunc(myJSONObject: JSONType_1 | JSONType_2) {
  if (myJSONObject.networkId.group && myJSONObject.networkId.group === 'myFavGroup') {
    differentFunction(myJSONObject) // this function takes input only in `JSONType_2`.
  }
}
```

Inside this `if` condition I want `myJSONObject` to have `JSONType_2` and not `JSONType_1 | JSONType_2` types.
As I want to send only `JSONType_2` to a different function.
Error which I get:

```
Argument of type 'JSONType_1 | JSONType_2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSONType_2'.
...
Types of property 'group' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"myFavGroup"'.
```

`myJSONObject` is received from another service who's structures are fixed. 2 Examples:

```
{
  networkId: {
    group: 'Desktop_group';
  };
  tasks: [
    { cmd: 'playMusic', songName: 'xyz' },
    { cmd: 'playVideo', videoName: 'abc' },
  ];
}
```

```
{
  networkId: {
    group: 'myFavGroup';
  };
  tasks: [
    { cmd: 'sendMusicList', path: '/home/user/musicFolder' },
    { cmd: 'sendFilesStats', path: '/home/user/someFolder' },
  ];
}
```

Notice all tasks JSON objects are also predefined and fixed. The only difference is that tasks for `myFavGroup` are different than any other group.

If there is a better way to code than what I am doing, I would appreciate your help in that too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you declaring myJSONObject or what is the structure? May be an example?

Comment: Edited the question by adding myJSONObject examples which I receive. @MBB

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks a bit dirty and I would consider some refactor, but!

```
// if group = 'myFavGroup' only for JSONType_2 you can exclude it for JSONType_1
interface NetworkIdOptions {
  group?: Exclude<'myFavGroup', string>; // <---
  individual?: string;
}
```

and

to make types compatible, you need to make `group` property optional for `JSONType_2`

```
export interface JSONType_2 {
  networkId: {
    group?: 'myFavGroup'; // <---
  };
}
```

This way after checking that `networkId.group` is equal to 'myFavGroup' your Typescript compiler will automagically understand that your argument is of type `JSONType_2` and you can successfully pass it to the `differentFunction`

Another solution would be just to use type assertion:

```
differentFunction(myJSONObject as JSONType_2)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, sorry for this dirty code, I am still learning typescript. Would you like to suggest how can I make it more cleaner? Also 1st solution didn't work it throws an error on `Types of property 'tasks' are incompatible.` as we can see tasks are different for `myFavGroup`. But 2nd solution worked.